# SQL Server, Remove Extra Spaces from nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a table column 'Name' in SQL Server 2012 which contains data in a form such as:

```
'  first      name  '
```

What I want is to remove while select, the extra  spaces (multiple spaces in between with only one space) and the result should be like:

```
'first name'
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: create UDF break words on space,reject row with empty word,finally append row with text and space

Comment: SQL Server does not support regex out of the box, so this is a hairy question.

Comment: The dupe + `ltrim` and `rtrim`.

Comment: you can do this " select substr(ltrim(xyz),1,index( ltrim(xyz) ,' ') )  as firstname,
trim(substr(ltrim(xyz),index( ltrim(xyz),' '))) as lastname,
firstname||' '||lastname as final_data
from space " just replcae the index function with SQL server equivalent.